# How to resize the first column if the second column doesn't have content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a site in Bootstrap. I have one page. In my page I have created two columns as so:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        Some information
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        Some information
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

How I can resize my first column from col-md9 to col-md-12 (full width) if the second column has no content?

Comment: Sounds like you need to either use flexbox, javascript or a server-side tech to do this

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use javascript / jQuery you can do it like this :

```
$('.row .col-md-3').each(function() {
    if (this.textContent.trim() == '') {
        $(this)
            .parent()
            .find('.col-md-9')
            .removeClass('col-md-9')        
            .addClass('col-md-12');
        $(this).remove();
    }    
})
```

if any `.col-md-3` is empty, the sibling div `.col-md-9` is "upgraded" to `.col-md-12` and the `.col-md-3` itself is beeing removed.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cy0kx44o/**

Answer (score 0):

Use table. If there is any content on the second column, wrap the content with a div that has minimum width.

```
    <table border=1 width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
      <tr>
         <td class='left'>My First Content</td>
         <td><div class='right'>My Second Content</div></td>
     </tr>
    </table>

    <style>
      @media (min-width: 768px){
       .right{
          min-width: 186px
       }
       .left{
          min-width: 558px;
       }
      }
     </style>
```

The table can be wrapped with `.col-md-12` as well.